# Pass different classes as parameters to a function Java

Tags: java, class, parameter-passing

I have several classes that all have *DoSomething()* method within them. And a  separate function that expects a Class as a parameter:

```
public void DoStuff(Class c) {
     c.DoSomething();
}
```

But this code throws error:  **DoSomething() is undefined for the type Class.** I also tried instantiating the Class like this:

```
public void DoStuff(Class c) {

Object o;

try {
   o = c.newInstance();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

And then calling the DoSomething() method, but i get the same error.

What's the correct way to pass a class as a parameter?

Comment: Your second method seems to be correct. Could  you post the entire error message?

Comment: `DoStuff()` != `DoSomething()`

Comment: actually an instance. I shouldn't have?

Comment: "expects a Class as a parameter" are you sure??

Comment: @ogzd what's your point? it's not the same yes, but ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an `interface` that declares your method `doSomething` like this:

```
   public interface Something {
      void doSomething();   
   }
```

and then have your class implement this interface like:

```
public class SomeClass implements Something {
    public void doSomething() {
        // do what?
    }
}
```

You can then do

```
public void DoStuff(Something pInstance) {
   pInstance.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: void doSomething() must be different for all SomeClass-es.

Comment: Great example, but would be cool to make another class implement that interface, and show some code that cycles the implementation, like: List <Something> things = Arrays.asList(new SomeClass(), new SomeOtherClass); and then do a for(Something s: thins) { s.doSomething()}.

Comment: @astralmaster I do not understand your objection. The declaration in the interface is devoid of implementation. It is the actual class that implements the declared method that provides the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code example is incorrect because `c` is of type `Class` which does **not** have `DoStuff()`

Your second code is more appropriate, just you need to `cast` your object to a type that have `DoStuff()` method (e.g. an `interface` that all your classes implement)

Alternatively, you can just call the method `DoSomething()` with reflection

e.g.,

```
Method method = c.getMethod("DoSomething");
Object obj = c.newInstance();
method.invoke(obj);
```

Comment: Yes but I don't always know which one that object will be. I have several objects that have DoStuff() method. I wanted a universalw ay to pass those objects.

Comment: Just use reflection to call the method, or have a common interface for all your classes

Comment: Is this good way when working with Threads? If DoStuff() is in different thread than the main()

Comment: You can make your `DoStuff()` method a thread-safe if you want regardless of the method you use to call it (i.e. reflection or via interface)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Interface that has a method `doSomething()` and you make all classes implement this Interface. You can then call `doSomething()` on all the classes.

Comment: Thanks I thought about this., if no easier way Im going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the type `Class` with the type `Object`. The class `Object` is directly or indirectly the superclass of all the classes you will ever create in Java (with the currently available versions of Java at least). Because every object extends the class `Object` you can pass every object to a method that expects a parameter of the type `Object`. The type `Class` is something entirely different. An object of the type `Class` (I almost confused my self there) is obtained by a class literal (`myInstance.class`) or reflection. I suspect you passed an instance of a class to `DoStuff()`, and hence the compiler complained it was not an object of the type `Class`. Change `Class` to `Object` and you'll be fine, except that you have to cast that object to a class that implements `DoSomething`

Answer (score -2):

I think what you really mean is that you are passing an *instance* of an Object to your `doStuff()` method, this Object then has a `doSomething()` method that you should be able to call. Unless you have an inheritance hierarchy, you would need to make your method take a parameter of type `Object` and cast to your specific `Object`.

```
public void doStuff(Object o) {
  if(o instanceof Class1) {
     Class1 c1 = (Class1)o;
     c1.doSomething();
  } 
  else if(o instanceof Class2) {
     Class2 c2 = (Class2)o;
     c2.doSomething();
  }
  else {
     ....
  }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what i meant yes, sorry.

Comment: This is actually a very bad way to get the desired functionality.

Comment: @Erik Notice I said without an inheritance realationship.

Comment: Because you are locking yourself in this way. If you want to add another class that has a doSomething() method, then you need to rewrite this method. This is also a very non-oop way of programming. Even if the classes implementing doSomething are not yours I would say wrap them in a class implementing the interface.